# Adding Switch to React Router

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a switch to my existing router to handle 404 errors.

```js
const AppRouter = () => (
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
  <div>
  <Switch>  //New
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />  //New
        <Route exact path="/" secure component={List} />
        <Route path="/home" secure component={List} />
        <Route path="/page/:id" secure component={page} />
  </Switch>  //New
  </div>
</ConnectedRouter>
);
export default AppRouter;
```

It works without the switch but when I add in the switch I get a 'string expected / undefined error

Comment: <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />  put this at the end of your routes

Comment: Move the '*' `Route` to the last position. `Switch` renders the **first** route that matches.

Comment: Doesn’t matter the order of the routes.  I still get an error at runtime.  Only Taking off the “switch”  removes the error.

Answer (score 0):

This was the Route that eventually worked

```
import { Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
```

and

```
 <Route path="*" exact component={NotFoundPage} />
```